# Failed to resolve: :places-maps-sdk-3.1.0-beta: while integrating Google Maps v3.1.0 in android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, google-places-api

I've been trying to integrate Google Maps v3.1.0 in my android app, along with the Places API, by [following the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/v3-client-migration). This is the dependencies' implementation in my *app-level* `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.maps:maps:3.1.0-beta'

//This is where gradle build is failing
implementation name:'places-maps-sdk-3.1.0-beta', ext:'aar'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.2'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils-v3:1.3.1'
```

On Gradle Build, I'm getting the following error:

```
Failed to resolve: :places-maps-sdk-3.1.0-beta:
Affected Modules: app
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by replacing

```
implementation name:'places-maps-sdk-3.1.0-beta', ext:'aar'
```

with

```
implementation files('libs/places-maps-sdk-3.1.0-beta.aar')
```

I hope that this will help you as well.